# how to find the discrete time fourier series of sin function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have this discrete signal sin($0.1 \cdot \pi n$) and I want to find the DTFS of it.

first I have found its fundamental period N which is 20 but what am struggling with is how am I going to find 29 values of CK.

so my question is: is there any other simpler way to find its DTFS.

NOTE: I don't want its DFT!

Comment: It might help if you spelled out what you are talking about without using acronyms.  (CK, DTFS, DFT)

Comment: DTFS = discrete time Fourier series and DTF = discrete Fourier transform and CK = is the constants